# git clone error error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream

Tags: git, github, windows-10

I keep receiving this error each time I try to clone a new repository, the second time I clone it, it works fine. What could be the cause of it and how to resolve it?

```
Cloning into 'Important-Documents'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 83, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (83/83), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 7 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream
error: 4241 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Comment: Do you have an antivirus or firewall other than the default, or are you using any sort of proxy or TLS MITM device?

Comment: @bk2204 thanks a lot for responding. This is a new computer but it did have McAfree pre installed.

Comment: I would remove it completely, restart the computer, and use Windows Defender instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error message in my android studio and I solved that by using my mobile data to clone the app and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this error too: So I clone the repo in parts using the command below:

1. Enter this command in the terminal or powershell `git clone --depth 1 <repo url>`
2. when the step 1 is done, change your directory to the  and
3. Enter this command `git fetch --unshallow`

If the still persist I'd advice you to turn-off your anti-virus and try the step again.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my case,

1. Speed up your network bandwidth
2. Try another terminal ( I got an error while using VS code, it resolved when I used cmd)